# Matching values in an iterative way in pandas

Tags: pandas, loops, rows, matching

I have got a pandas dataframe including data from two different dataframes and I need to match and produce scores in an iterative way for each row based on their index (header) as in the image below. Is that possible in pandas? Any suggestion is very welcome. thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: What's your expected output, also please post data as text

Comment: thanks for your comment. Basically I want to match each row value with certain index with the other row values beginning with index 0 (header). For example, first of all "r" with "reiner", "de", "adelhart" and "toorop" and then "van" with "reiner", "de", "adelhart" and "toorop" (it goes like this)and  produce a similarity scoring in a separate column. I hope this is much clearer now.

Comment: you first columns only contains r valyues its still not clear